# Optional output cursor as parameter

Tags: oracle, parameters, cursor, default-value, optional-parameters

I'm trying to cater for two applications.

One calls a procedure with 2 cursors, the other with 1.

Both are `OUT SYS_REFCURSOR`.

Because of the difference in definition of the procedure, the change to one application will break the other.

I am wondering if its possible to have the same procedure with both `OUT SYS_REFCURSOR` but with the second parameter as optional. This is done in other parts of the project by defining a default value.

I have tried googling and defining default values but to no avail. This doesnt seem to be a very common issue.

Is there a way to have this definition with an optional `OUT SYS_REFCURSOR` ?

Here is my code:

```
PROCEDURE Proc_GetQ (qList OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, qStack OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
```

I would like **qStack** to be optional.

Thanks,
JFIT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [method overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)?

```
PROCEDURE Proc_GetQ (qList OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, qStack OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
PROCEDURE Proc_GetQ (qList OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
```

Create a procedure with the same name, similar logic (better call 2-parameter version inside and pass only one outside), but only one `OUT` parameter.

Comment: Great thanks. For the question i was simplifying. There is 2 methods that need this. I'm getting this error now: too many declarations of 'Proc_GetQ' match this call. 
Even though i've done as you requested. It seems to be coming from a procedure calling one of these. but the definitions are different so not sure why it can't match.

Comment: PLS-00307, huh? Are these 'Proc_GetQ' in the same package? Can you list declarations of all the methods in this package? And the piece of code where you call these procedures too.

Comment: @JFit it would be nice to see your new one-parameter procedure code also.

Comment: Its all good now thanks @miraclefoxx - I used the method you used exactly as you showed it. pulled the cursor out into the smaller method and wrapped the origonal. Thanks so much for your answer :)